# How can I generate html from OpenAPI 3.1 schema?

Tags: yaml, openapi, openapi-generator, api-doc

I've got a [schema](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_1/null-types-with-type-array.yaml) in OpenAPI 3.1 spec that was [released](https://www.openapis.org/blog/2020/06/18/openapi-3-1-0-rc0-its-here) recently. How can I generate html from that? I used to run

```
openapi-generator generate -i PathToMyInputDefinitionFile.yaml -g html -o /PathToOutputFolder
```

But as far as I can see, `openapi-generator` doesn't [support](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/9083) it yet.

I'm interested specifically in python package that has a support of `3.1.0` already.

Comment: Until now there are still no generators for that, as a couple of bugs in OpenApi's own schema validators are open. We might need to wait a while for that, but libraries for 3.0.3 are available till then.

Comment: As of today openapi-generator can still not handle OpenAPI 3.1.0, there is an [issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/9083) however

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAPI 3.1 with openapi-generator-cli typescript-fetch: JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'openapi': was expecting (JSON String, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71855162/openapi-3-1-with-openapi-generator-cli-typescript-fetch-jsonparseexception-unr)