# OpenAPI 3.1 with openapi-generator-cli typescript-fetch: JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'openapi': was expecting (JSON String, ...)

Tags: typescript, fetch, openapi, openapi-generator-cli

I would like to generate a typescript-fetch client using **openapi-generator-cli**. The specs were generated by Stoplight using **OpenAPI 3.1** format. However when I run the command

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i resources/openapi/Attribute.yaml -o ../test/ -g typescript-fetch
```

I get the error

```
[ERROR] i.s.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter - failed to read resource listing
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'openapi': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (String)"openapi: 3.1.0 ... ]
```

With another openapi code generator ([openapi-typescript-codegen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-typescript-codegen)) I can generate client code without a problem so the specs are not only validated but usable. This makes suspect that the issue is with the OpenAPI version.

Is OpenAPI 3.1 supported by openapi-typescript-codegen or is there something I can do to adapt my specs file ?

I am using

- openapi-generator-cli 5.4.0
- OpenAPI 3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenAPI 3.1 is yet not supported in Swagger and other tools, including openapi-generator-cli and that's the cause of the error.

Here is the last (significant) [update](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/1535#issuecomment-936707841), the team is still working on it.

Comment: This is pretty aggravating at this point. The spec has been at 3.1 for a while now, and it adds crucial (and long-overdue) capabilities.